# Change color of highcharter r choropleth map

Tags: r, highcharts, choropleth

Trying to change the color for a highcharter choropleth map, but all the obvious ways don't seem to do it. Example attempt:

```
mp <- highchart() %>%
      hc_add_series_map(usgeojson, Kaiser_insurance_coverage_2016, name = "Female",
                        value = "Female", joinBy = c("woename", "Location")) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(color = "#C5C889")) %>%
      hc_legend(valueDecimals = 0, valueSuffix = "%",
                verticalAlign = "top")
```

And then alternative attempt:

```
hcmap("custom/world-eckert3-highres", 
  data = mpw,
  value = "FertilityRate",
  joinBy = c("hc-a2", "hc-a2"),
  name = "Fertility Rate",
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
  borderColor = "#8C89C8",
  color = "#C5C889",
  borderWidth = 0.1,
  tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2, valuePrefix = "$", valueSuffix = " USD")) %>%
hc_title("Fertility Rate")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
map %>% hc_colorAxis(minColor = "#C5C889", maxColor = "#434348")
```

Comment: Hi, any idea on how to do this with more than two categories?